# Contradiction in information resources on capturing UV light with a digital sensor

Tags: sensor

I encounter a contradiction.

Many resources state that a digital sensor are unsensitive to UV light. Even wikipedia, "However, newer photographic film and digital cameras are highly insensitive to UV wavelengths." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_filter. 
Digital Photography Review goes even to the point that a digital photographer won't even need it on a beach (an UV-light rich area). "digital sensors are not and hence do not need UV filters in even bright sunlight". http://www.dpreview.com/articles/8049091537/the-uv-filter

While other resources state that digital sensor are sensitive to UV light. [Are digital sensors sensitive to UV?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2262/are-digital-sensors-sensitive-to-uv)

Can someone clarify this contradiction?

My prognosis is that a digital sensor is sensitive to UV light, but sensor manufactures include an UV blocking system on the sensor. But I don't know if that's true. I do know that IR light is blocked through a IR-absorption glass on the sensor itself.

Is my prognosis correct?

Comment: A lot depends on just *how* sensitive at *what wavelengths of the UV light spectrum* a sensor needs to be to be considered *sensitive to UV light*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most digital sensors are sensitive to UV to some degree, and most have UV/IR cut filters installed over them to keep that sensitivity from throwing off visible light colors.  However, removing the cut filter to let in the full spectrum, or using a pass filter and long exposures, doesn't really solve the issue of allowing the camera to shoot in UV, because the majority of *lenses* also have UV cut coatings on them. Few lenses are suitable for UV shooting, and the ones that are tend to be expensive and rare (e.g., the [UV-Nikkor 105 f/4.5](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/special/105UVmm.htm)), which is why this is a much rarer and more esoteric form of photography than IR shooting.  It's most commonly done by forensic photographers.

See:  [All You Ever Wanted to Know About Digital UV and IR Photography, But Could Not Afford to Ask](http://www.naturfotograf.com/UV_IR_rev01UV.html)

Comment: Do you have a link of a photo of an UV/IR cut filter which is installed on a sensor?

Comment: Nevermind... http://www.365astronomy.com/astronomik-lfilter-uvir-blocker-clipfilter-for-canon-eos-p-3577.html?zenid=d4f1f523f4c033c6a42262f17d13b0b6

Comment: @Julian here's more visual aids for a variety of cameras: http://www.lifepixel.com/tutorials/infrared-diy-tutorials. Lifepixel does IR and full-spectrum conversion of cameras by removing the installed filter, and then replacing it.